# Whats Wrong with my Cypher FOREACH?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can some one please help me understand whats wrong with my Cypher query

```
MATCH (sys:System{Name:'MYSYS' , Version:'1.0'})
FOREACH (item in [
  {
    itemObj: {
        ItemID: "DOMAIN",
        Name: "DOMAIN",
        TypeID: "",
        Physical: "",
        Logical: ""
        },
    parameters: {
        VERSIONNUM: "",
        QUALSTATE: "",
        VERSION: "",
        CREATEDBY: "",
        DATECREATED: "",
        MODIFIEDBY: "",
        VERSIONDATE: "",
        BLCKCOMMENT1: "",
        BLCKCOMMENT2: "",
        BLCKCOMMENT3: "",
        BLCKCOMMENT4: "",
        ORIGASSIGN: "",
        CANETYPE: "",
        FULLITEMNAME: "",
        DESC: "",
        SCANPNTDTL: "",
        SCANASSOCDSP: "",
        ADSIPATH: "",
        ASSIGNABLE: ""
        }
    },
    {
    itemObj: {
        ItemID: "COMPUTERS",
        Name: "COMPUTERS",
        TypeID: "",
        Physical: "",
        Logical: ""
        },
    parameters: {
        VERSIONNUM: "",
        QUALSTATE: "",
        VERSION: "",
        CREATEDBY: "",
        DATECREATED: "",
        MODIFIEDBY: "",
        VERSIONDATE: "",
        BLCKCOMMENT1: "",
        BLCKCOMMENT2: "",
        BLCKCOMMENT3: "",
        BLCKCOMMENT4: "",
        ORIGASSIGN: "",
        CANETYPE: "",
        FULLITEMNAME: "",
        DESC: "",
        SCANPNTDTL: "",
        SCANASSOCDSP: "",
        ASSIGNABLE: ""
        }
    },
    {
    itemObj: {
        ItemID: ".htm",
        Name: ".htm",
        TypeID: "",
        Physical: "",
        Logical: ""
        },
    parameters: {
        FileName: ""
    }
  }
] | 
CREATE (p:Parameter) SET p=item.parameters 
MERGE (it:Item { ItemID: item.itemObj.ItemID}) ON CREATE SET it=item.itemObj 
MERGE (sys)-[HAS_ITEM]->(it)-[:HAS_PARAMETERS]->(p) )
```

I end up getting this error

```
A single relationship type must be specified for CREATE (line 77, column 12)
```

I am trying to learn to use foreach as its seams very fast in case of bulk insert, so any help here is really welcome.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `:` when declaring relationship type. On the last line, `[HAS_ITEM]` should be `[:HAS_ITEM]`.

Comment: Can't imagine how I missed that for almost an hour. Thanks! BTW can you pls also help me on how I can set a property on the relation as this fails to register a property on the relationsgip `FOREACH (target in {targetsStrat} | MERGE (dest:Item { ItemID: target.Id}) CREATE UNIQUE (srcVar)-[r:STRATEGY]->(dest) SET r.SrcParam= target.SrcParam)`